# Rails 3 design for a has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Model that represents a purchase

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
```

So basically each purchase belongs to both a user and an item that is being purchased. Now here is my problem, I could nest purchase on item, so that when user is purchasing he will go to:

/item/1/purchase/new

That would work fine, but I also like the user to be able to go to /user/1/purchases/1/edit etc.Basically purchase would need to be nested onto both user and item which you can't.

Right now I am basically adding more restful actions to both the user and item, like /item/1/purchase and /user/1/purchase/ etc, but that leads to growing the controllers quite a lot. Is this the only way or could you nest a resource to 2 resources ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, they can nest in both. Rails won't stop you from making whatever routes you want.

However, I'd recommend nesting only certain actions under certain parent resources. For instance, `new` and `create` can go under items, since that makes sense as you're reaching the purchase from the item, but `show` and the like might make more sense under the user, if it really needs to be nested under anything at all.